# Mysqli_error() returns a blank page

Tags: php, stored-procedures, mysqli

I am trying to run a query that calls a stored procedure but this does not work due to some errors. Unfortunately, I can't see the error because mysqli_error() keeps returning a blank screen. Please do I get the error to show. I have been on this  for hours.

Here is my code:

```
$ID = $_SESSION['ID'];
$sql = "CALL selCash('$ID')";
$result = mysqli_query($this->con,$sql); 
mysqli_next_result($this->con); 
if($result === false){
    die(mysqli_error($this->con));
}else{
    die("good");
}
return $result;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try display all errors:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Also you can use `try catch` and set mysqli error reports to all:

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT | MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL);

try {
    $result = mysqli_query($this->con,$sql); 
    mysqli_next_result($this->con); 
    if($result === false){
        die(mysqli_error($this->con));
    }else{
        die("good");
    }
} catch (mysqli_sql_exception $e) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Not sure why this had a negative vote as mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT | MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL); fixed this for me